# Writing specific symbols

Tags: symbols

Can you help me to write the following symbol.

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Have you checked the [Comprehensive Symbols List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)?

Comment: In what field is the symbol used? This may help in identifying a possible solution.

Comment: May be mixing `\perp` and `=`. I think first in `$\underline{\underline{\displaystyle\perp}}$` but in this way the bottom lines are wider.

Comment: @Closers: You have found the symbol in ["The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) or via ["Detexify"](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)? Then please post the result, I could not found the symbol in neither of them.

Comment: You could have a look at the CircuiTikZ package. It has this symbol as well as a lot of other symbols you might need.

Answer (score 10):

### Identification of the symbol

For the case the symbol has a Unicode code point, I have drawn the symbol in [shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/). The [result](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/9178):

```
U+23DA EARTH GROUND.
```

### Finding a font that contains the symbol

Next I tried the [character search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) of [FileFormat.Info](http://www.fileformat.info/index.htm) that lists some fonts as [result](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23da/fontsupport.htm). I recognized the OpenType font `FreeMono` as part of TeX Live.

### Example for LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX

The font `FreeMono` is a OpenType font that requires either LuaTeX or XeTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\earthground}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{FreeMono.otf}^^^^23da%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \earthground
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Including as image

If you are using `pdflatex`, then the symbol could be included as image, e.g.:

```
%%% earthground.tex %%%
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}%
  \fontspec{FreeMono.otf}%
  ^^^^23da
\end{document}
```

Then the file is converted to the image file `earthground.pdf` via:

```bash
$ lualatex earthground
```

Users of `dvips` can convert the file to PostScript:

```
$ pdftops -eps earthground.pdf
```

Finally the image is included as usually:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\includegraphics{earthground}
```

Comment: That was a handy tip (`pdflatex` + `fontspec`).

Comment: @JagathAR: Thanks, fixed. Feel free to correct such kind of obvious typos.

Comment: Oops! I really thought it was possible using `fontspec`! ha ha. OK.  So we need to run `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Answer (score 0):

In you question, the context is not clear. However, the following will generate a symbol similar to one that you are asking:

```
$\stackrel{\bot}{\hspace*{.3pt}\raise 2.5pt\hbox{\rule{4pt}{.3pt}\kern-4pt\lower 2pt\hbox{\rule{4pt}{.3pt}}}}$
```